# Issue referencing value inside json response

Tags: javascript, json

Uploading a photo to an external cloud CDN returns to me a json result which has the relevant information about that photo I have just uploaded. One field in particular is called the public_id; this is what I need to store in my database.

The response looks like this:

```
{
  "public_id":"ddbkckukliohfc0rydsa",
  "version":1432446422,
  "signature":"4cd9b48e1e0504792fa0a468d6a6285ceb6a466a",
  "width":158,
  "height":158,
  "format":"jpg",
  "resource_type":"image",
  "created_at":"2015-05-24T05:47:02Z",
  "tags":[],
  "bytes":6741,
  "type":"upload",
  "etag":"34af2941f140b76ef1cb9f4a549b04a5"
}
```

When it returns it calls the following js function.

```
   function(error, result) {
     console.log(error, result);
     var t = result["public_id"];
     alert(t);
   }
```

How it stands at the moment when I `alert(t)` I get underfined, yet when I change it to:

```
   function(error, result) {
     console.log(error, result);
     var t = result.public_id;
     alert(t);
   }
```

I also get undefined?

Whats the deal?

Comment: Seems that un-escaped `"` double quotes around property is causing problem for JSON.parse().

Answer (score 0):

If the output you included is the result of the `console.log`, you have the string result, and you need to call `JSON.parse()` on the string to get the object.

I believe this will work better for you.

```
function(error, result) {
  console.log(error, result);
  var theObj = JSON.parse(result);
  var t = theObj.public_id;
  alert(t);
}
```

Comment: just tried what you have suggested, but I get 

JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data on the JSON.parse(result); line

Comment: @ScottAtkinson That is odd. It looks like well-formed JSON. Since your console.log emits error & result together without annotation, is the API for certain using node style callbacks, or could this be being called as a simple success handler such that the error parameter is actually your data?

Comment: I have just split the console log up so I now have two, one for error and the other for result, error prints null in the console, whilst result prints what I have shown in the. I am 95% sure they are using node style callbacks.

Comment: by doing the following alert(result[0]["public_id"]); I am able to get the relevant field.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a node-style callback for certain. Quite odd. if you copy/paste the console log content directly into an online JSON parser/viewer does it work fine?

Comment: @ScottAtkinson - ah so the API is giving it back to you as an array. Interesting.